# For holomorphic function on an open set, does there exists a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to it on any compact subset?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to give a proof or counterexample of the following statement: For holomorphic function $f$ on an open set $\Omega$, there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)_{n\geq1}$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on a compact subset $S\subset\Omega$.

I believe this statement is not true. I was thinking the following case: Let $f(z)=1/z$, $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $S$ to be an annulus with the inner boudary really close to origin, like $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:a\leq|z|\leq 1\}$ for some very small $a$. Then I stuck at this point. Am I on the right track?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan's_theorem

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp It's not as related as the more elementary Runge's theorem.

Comment: Well, I am better with polynomials. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're definitely on the right track. Now integrate $1/z$ on a circle centered at $0$ and also integrate the polynomials that supposedly uniformly approximate it on said compact circle.

It's sort of an interesting question because it depends crucially on the topology of $\Omega$: the answer is yes if and only if $\Omega$ is simply connected.

Comment: How do you do that when $\Omega$ is simply connected?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is simply connected, then $\mathbb{C}^* \setminus \Omega$ is connected (this is how many complex analysis authors define simple connectedness), so it has only one component. Now exhaust $\Omega$ by compact sets $K_n$ such that each component of the complement of each $K_n$ intersects the complement of $\Omega$. Since the one component of the complement of $\Omega$ contains infinity, using Runge's theorem you can find rational functions $p_n$ with poles only at infinity (that is, polynomials) such that $\sup_{K_n}|p_n-f|<1/n$. This sequence works.

Comment: Conway is very careful about finding such an exhaustion of $\Omega$, and so is Rudin. Some textbooks (like Stein and Shakarchi) kind of skip it...

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I cited Mergelyan's theorem above, but I didn't think of such an exhaustion when I did. Wouldn't it be enough to define $K_n := \{\omega\in\Omega : \operatorname{dist}(\omega,\partial\Omega)\ge 1/n\}$ (when $\Omega$ is bounded)?

Comment: Yeah that's the way to do it (well actually you should intersect that set with the closed ball of radius $n$ centered at $0$ in case $\Omega$ is unbounded). You just have to be a little careful to prove that the components of the complement all intersect the complement of $\Omega$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you. :-) Actually, when you apply Mergelyan, you only need that $\mathbb C\setminus K_n$ is connected.

Comment: That's true, but I think the proof of Mergelyan's theorem is a lot more sophisticated and probably even applies Runge's theorem in the same way (to be honest, I've never actually read a proof of it though :P).

Comment: Me neither. But as far as I know, it is in Rudin's book. I just like the "simplicity" of the statement. Easy to understand - very hard to prove.